# PHP object property string concatenation in foreach without setting empty string first

Tags: php

I have some WordPress custom fields data that I am looping through and creating a comma separated string. The (small) issue is that I get a warning if I don't set the property as empty / null etc before looping.

I guess you can't concatenate a string if it doesn't yet exist. Although I get the warning, the foreach does what I need an there are no errors.

To stop the warning I have set the property as an empty string to start:

```
$memlog->postnominals = "";
foreach (get_field('post_nominals', $post->id) as $postnominal) {
    $memlog->postnominals .= $postnominal->post_title . ", ";
}
```

Although not a big issue, I would rather know if there is a way I can do this without setting an empty string?

Comment: `$memlog->postnominals = join(', ', array_column(get_field(...), 'post_title'))`…?

Comment: declare that property at class

Comment: eg `public $postnominals = '';`

Comment: @deceze Cool solution, didn't know about doing it that way thanks. If you want to post an answer ill accept it.

Comment: @KsaR That would be the initial thought, but its not for a class its a new stdClass just for creating an object to use (legacy WP site...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use concatenation to begin with, [`join`](http://php.net/join) an array, that way you also don't have to strip off the last `,` afterwards:

```
$memlog->postnominals = join(', ', array_column(get_field(...), 'post_title'));
```

`array_column` only works with objects in PHP 7+, for older versions use a map:

```
$memlog->postnominals = join(', ', array_map(
    function ($p) { return $p->post_title; }, 
    get_field(...)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use array then implode that data from array to form comma separated string.

Example:

```
        $aa = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c');
        foreach ($aa as $k => $v) {
            $b[] = $v;
        }
        print_r(implode(',', $b));
```

Comment: Just to point it out: in this particular sample the `foreach` is completely superfluous. You could `implode` `$aa` directly.

Comment: Yeah, actually you are right. 
But if you want to perform some extra task then you can this loop otherwise just use implode.